# How to iterate and sum value of data coming from firestore with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function to retrieve data from firebase as follows,

```
getTrips() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('trips')
        .orderBy('date')
        .where('date', isGreaterThan: DateTime.now())
        // .where('date', isGreaterThan: DateTime.parse(widget.searchTrip.date))
        .get();
    setState(() {
      _allTrips = data.docs;
    });
    return data.docs;
  }
```

I want to iterate the List _allTrips or data.docs and get sum of values in the field 'seats' which is int values on the collection being retrieved by abpve code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: if your `data.docs` are a list,   you can use `fold()` method to get sum of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a .then() after the .get() and do the following:

```
var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('trips')
        .orderBy('date')
        .where('date', isGreaterThan: DateTime.now())
        // .where('date', isGreaterThan: DateTime.parse(widget.searchTrip.date))
        .get()
.then((snapshot){
_allTrips = snapshot.docs;
_allTrips.forEach((element)=> totalNumber+=element.data()['seats'])
};
```